# Google Places API Search with specific search term data

Tags: google-places-api, location-based

I want to make server api that gets data with search terms of about 300 specific search terms.
I want to implement that using Google Places API.
The search type is divided by Google Category and Name Only.
First, I tried to implement that using TextSearch of Google Places API, but it always return 60 data, so it can't show data according to the current location that user locates.
So, I tried to use Nearby Search, but after getting data, I must filter those data according to about 300 search terms. 
How can I implement this?
I attach some of search terms below.

Search Type       Search Term         App Category          Place Type
Name Only     Arby's          Restaurant        restaurant
Google Category   Art Gallery         Recreation        art_gallery

Anyone can help this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're getting the data you need using Nearby Search, but you need to select specific data from that, is that correct?

If you are getting this data via XML, just implement some code to parse the XML file for the data tags that you want to keep. There will be a lot of information on Google for parsing XML, but that depends on what language you are using on the server.

Comment: I use php for server api and return json data.